# Downloading and accessing data from github python

Tags: python, git, pandas

Hi I'm going through Python for Data analysis and I'd like to analyze the data he goes through in the book. In chapter 9, he uses the data below. However, I'm having a difficult time understanding how to utilize the data in my ipython notebook once I download it to my github application on mac.

The stock data is here: https://github.com/pydata/pydata-book/blob/master/ch09/stock_px.csv

I clicked "open" which downloaded a large file on my github application. It looks like the below. How do I get this data to open in my ipython notebook?

**Looking at other stackoverflow questions, I know I can just download the zip file, which I am doing as well. It would be cool to know how to use the github application efficiently.

Right clicking and saving the csv file seems to save the json/html file

[image]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should be able to just use the `url` of the raw version (a link to the raw version is a button on the link you provided) and then read it into a dataframe directly using `read_csv`:

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pydata/pydata-book/master/ch09/stock_px.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url,index_col=0,parse_dates=[0])

print df.head(5)

            AAPL   MSFT    XOM     SPX
2003-01-02  7.40  21.11  29.22  909.03
2003-01-03  7.45  21.14  29.24  908.59
2003-01-06  7.45  21.52  29.96  929.01
2003-01-07  7.43  21.93  28.95  922.93
2003-01-08  7.28  21.31  28.83  909.93
```

Edit: a brief explanation about the options I used to read in the file:

```
df = pd.read_csv(url,index_col=0,parse_dates=[0])
```

The first column (column = 0) is a column of dates in the file and because it had no column name it looked like it was meant to be the index; `index_col=0` makes it the index and parse_dates[0] tells read_csv to parse column=0 (the first column) as dates.

Comment: THank you! On that note, can you help me understand what index_col=0 does? Doc says 'column to use as the row labels of the DataFrame.' What does it mean to put 0 in there? same with parse_dates = 0?

Comment: one more thing: for this link - how would I upload the data for csv_mindex and code for ipython_bug.py? https://github.com/pydata/pydata-book/commit/063039f4495ef11fd7210a520749017955fc3691

Comment: Added a brief explanation of `index_col = 0` and `parse_dates=[0]` to my answer.

Comment: Thanks so much Karl! if you could also answer the question about getting the data for csv_mindex (because there's no raw url link), that would be much appreciated! :D

Comment: There is a raw file: [csv_mindex.csv](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pydata/pydata-book/master/ch06/csv_mindex.csv)

Comment: really odd: sometimes it looks like there isn't a master file. thanks a lot for pointing me to the file!

Answer (score 4):

First convert the github csv file to raw in order to access the data, follow the  link below in comment on how to convert csv file to raw .

```
import pandas as pd

url_data = (r'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oderofrancis/rona/main/Countries-Continents.csv')

data_csv = pd.read_csv(url_data)

data_csv.head()
```

Comment: how to convert csv file to raw in github https://projectosyo.wixsite.com/datadoubleconfirm/single-post/2019/04/15/reading-csv-data-from-github-python