# Pandas: read csv from github

Tags: python, pandas

I created a public github repo and I uploaed a .csv file that I would like to read

https://github.com/emanuelemassaro/pois/blob/master/indonesia_education.csv

This what I am doing

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import requests
url="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/emanuelemassaro/pois/indonesia_education.csv"
s=requests.get(url).content
c=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s.decode('utf-8')))
```

this is the output that I get

```
c
    400: Invalid request
```

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23464138/downloading-and-accessing-data-from-github-python

Comment: That url gives me a 400 invalid request in the browser. Something is wrong with your url.

Answer (score 2):

Your url is an invalid github request. You forgot the branch name. Using the corrected url, you can read simply with `pd.read_csv`:

```py
import pandas as pd

url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/emanuelemassaro/pois/master/indonesia_education.csv"
pd.read_csv(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are just missing the branch, e.g. master:

Try for example:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/emanuelemassaro/pois/master/indonesia_education.csv

Instead of:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/emanuelemassaro/pois/indonesia_education.csv

Answer (score 0):

The true url of csv is:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/emanuelemassaro/pois/master/indonesia_education.csv
```

not this:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/emanuelemassaro/pois/indonesia_education.csv
```